# How to render features that are just outside the map canvas extent in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: layers, symbology, qgis-3

I am trying to generate a cloudy mask, following the recipe in "[Qgis Map Design 2nd ed. Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0998547743)".  For the most part, I have it working.

But when panning around, the mask changes.  And I think that is due to features just outside map canvas extent not being factored into the size expression calculation. Or the rendering of the the entire layer at that extent.

Here's an example of an area where it should be obscured, but isn't:
[image]

And if I pan a bit over, the area is now obscured because those features are now being rendered:
[image]

Is there a way to configure the layer to render features that are a specific distance outside the visible extent.  So that features just outside the visible extent with large symbols are drawn on the canvas?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? It seems to be a strange behavior, I would not expect default QGIS settings to act like this.